# Can't start mysqld after crash

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysqld

Prehistory:

I wanted to see how mysql handles in tables with millions of rows. So, I started to insert bunches of rows in one table. After ~80 millions mysql server has gone away and didn't start after. Then I installed mariadb and later removed it. Somehow installed mysql-server again. Lost any pieces of previous config files. After that, I realized that I need one database which engine is innodb. I have old data files. So I need to start mysqld with old data or dump that particular database somehow. Can't find a way to do last thing.

My config is Ubuntu 16.4 i686 and mysql-server 5.7.

To start mysqld I tried innodb_force_recovery of 4,5 and 6. No result. Here is /var/log/mysql/error.log:

```
2017-02-28T09:29:14.103113Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits:     max_open_files: 1024 (requested 6161)
2017-02-28T09:29:14.103225Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 3000)
2017-02-28T09:29:14.280958Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2017-02-28T09:29:14.283429Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 30221 ...
2017-02-28T09:29:14.289321Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2017-02-28T09:29:14.289355Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-02-28T09:29:14.289361Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2017-02-28T09:29:14.289366Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-02-28T09:29:14.289372Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2017-02-28T09:29:14.289377Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2017-02-28T09:29:14.289625Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2017-02-28T09:29:14.289725Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2017-02-28T09:29:14.291134Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2017-02-28T09:29:14.302212Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-02-28T09:29:14.304956Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2017-02-28T09:29:14.318160Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-02-28T09:29:14.319899Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 14888319000
2017-02-28T09:29:14.809862Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 14893561856
2017-02-28T09:29:15.317674Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 14890153984
2017-02-28T09:29:15.839489Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 14895396864
2017-02-28T09:29:16.147646Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 14898570815
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150245Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150258Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150355Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 0 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318633]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150363Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 1 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318634]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150369Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 2 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318635]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150380Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 3 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318636]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150386Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 4 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318637]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150392Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 5 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318638]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150397Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 6 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318639]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150403Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 7 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318640]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150409Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 8 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318641]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150415Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 9 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318642]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150420Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 10 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318643]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150426Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 11 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318644]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150444Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 12 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318645]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150451Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 13 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318646]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150456Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 14 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318647]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150462Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 15 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318648]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150468Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 16 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318649]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150474Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 17 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318650]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150479Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 18 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318651]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150485Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 19 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318652]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150491Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 20 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318653]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150496Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 21 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318654]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150502Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 22 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318655]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150565Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 24 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318720]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150571Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 25 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318721]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150577Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 26 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318722]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150583Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 27 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318723]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150589Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 28 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318724]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150594Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 29 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318684]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150600Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 30 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318685]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150606Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 31 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318686]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150612Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 32 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318687]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150617Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 33 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318688]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150623Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 34 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318689]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150629Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 35 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318690]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150635Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 36 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318691]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150640Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 37 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318692]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150646Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 38 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318693]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150656Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 39 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318694]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150662Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 40 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318695]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150668Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 41 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318696]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150673Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 42 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318697]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150679Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 43 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318698]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150685Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 44 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318699]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150691Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 45 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318700]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150696Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 46 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318701]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150702Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 47 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318702]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150708Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 48 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318703]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150714Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 49 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318704]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150719Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 50 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318705]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150725Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 51 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318706]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150731Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 52 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318707]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150737Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 53 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318708]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150742Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 54 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318709]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150748Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 55 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318710]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150754Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 56 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318711]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150760Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 57 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318712]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150765Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 58 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318713]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150771Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 59 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318714]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150777Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 60 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318715]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150783Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 61 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318716]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150788Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 62 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318717]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150794Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 63 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318718]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150800Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 64 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318719]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150809Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 65 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318623]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150815Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 66 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318624]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150821Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 67 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318625]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150826Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 68 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318626]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150832Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 69 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318627]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150838Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 70 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318628]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150843Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 71 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318629]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150853Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 72 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318630]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150859Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 73 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318631]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150865Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 74 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318632]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150871Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 75 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318149]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150876Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 76 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318150]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150882Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 77 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318151]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150888Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 78 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=318152]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150894Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 79 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=234050]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150900Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 80 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=234051]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150906Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 81 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=234052]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150911Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 82 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=234053]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150917Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 83 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=234054]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150923Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 84 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=317530]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.150929Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 85 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=317503]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.151243Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 92 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=315793]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.151252Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 93 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=315794]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.151258Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 94 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=315795]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.151264Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 95 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=263390]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.151270Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 96 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=262144]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.151281Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 97 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=285943]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.151288Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 98 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=285944]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.151293Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 99 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=285945]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.151299Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Page 100 in the doublewrite buffer is not within space bounds: page [page id: space=1201, page number=285946]
2017-02-28T09:29:16.205193Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 2017-02-28T09:29:16.205262Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 234400 in space 1201, space name insert_test/tbl0, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.
2017-02-28T09:29:16.205270Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Server exits.
```

Comment: you can start with adding  innodb_force_recovery tag in my.ini/my.cnf(MySQL Configuration) file and setting its values starting from 1 to 6 based on severity. This will force start the MySQL service. you can refer https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html

Before you start this I recommend to copy whole data folder to some safe place.

Comment: One more quick question did you remove ib log files from the data/default directory?

Comment: I didn't remove any file from data directory.

Comment: I tried innodb_force_recovery from 4 to 6 - no result. And even can't remember any significant change in log with this option.

Answer (score 2):

The error message at the end of the logs you posted, points to a possible mismatch of ibdata file name mismatch.

Have a look at the old data files that you have (/var/lib/mysql is the default directory unless you changed it). Check name of ibdata file (it's usually called ibdata1). Match this name with what's in /etc/mysql/my.cnf or /etc/my.cnf. Start MySQL and see if it comes up.

If this doesn't work:

- copy old data files to a directory of your choice
- change owner & group of this folder and all sub-folders and files to mysql (chown -R mysql:mysql [your new directory])
- edit your my.cnf and set datadir to the new directory where you copied the MySQL data files)
- Start MySQL server and see what you get in the mysqld.log file
- If you get MySQL running, run mysql_upgrade (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html) to upgrade old data to MySQL 5.7 if your old data was from another version of MySQL.

Comment: Have searched through /etc/mysql for "ibdata" - nothing found. Can add this folder here if it can help.

Comment: @edwvee ibdata file is usually in /var/lib/mysql/

Comment: I meant that there are no settings pointing on any ibdata file.

Comment: @edwvee what is size of your old/original ibdata1 file and what's the size of the same file in /var/lib/mysql directory?

Comment: In folder with old files (which I currently use to run mysqld) ibdata1 is 146800640 bytes. In folder that came with installation (and with which mysqld is able to start) ibdata1 is 12582912 bytes (little strange: i didn't add any database in fresh installation files).

Comment: @edwvee, it seems to me that you'll have to recover the required & crashed innodb table on a fresh install of MySQL using the .ibd and .frm files for the said table (I am assuming you had innodb_file_per_table=1 set so the crashed table has it's .ibd available to you). Have a look at http://www.chriscalender.com/tag/innodb-error-tablespace-id-in-file/ for detailed instruction. Not straight forward but I think your database crash has corrupted the innodb tablespace in such a way that usual recovery methods don't work.